# Cygwin shell not detected on Windows system

Tags: c, windows, makefile, arm, cygwin

I am trying to compile a file using an ARM (RVCT 3.1) compiler.

The makefile looks something like this (pasting extract)

```
AS        = armasm
LD        = armlink
CC        = armcc
TCC       = armcc
#TCC       = tcc
CPP       = armcpp
TCPP      = tcpp
AR        = armar
NM        = nm

ifeq    ($(TERM),cygwin)
    RM = rm
        RM_OPT = -rf
else
    RM = del
        RM_OPT =
endif

# Standard CFLAGS
ENDIAN            := --li

CFLAGS :=         -g -O2 -Otime --forceinline --cpu ARM7EJ-S  $(ENDIAN)  \
              --apcs /interwork  --fpu softvfp  --fpmode ieee_fixed  \
              --bss_threshold=0  --split_sections \
              --md --no_depend_system_headers --depend_format=unix

ASFLAGS :=       --keep -g --cpu ARM7EJ-S $(ENDIAN) \
             --apcs /interwork \
             --md

LINKFLAGS :=     --debug --remove --scatter $(BUILD).mem \
             --map --symdefs $(BUILD).sym --keep SDK_Callback.o\(*\) \
             --list linker.txt --info sizes,totals,veneers,unused \
             --errors output.txt --entry SDK_Main \
             --elf --output

ARFLAGS :=       -ru
```

when I run the make command I get an error like this

```
Assembling SDK_Callback.s......
armasm --keep -g --cpu ARM7EJ-S --li --apcs /interwork --md -o  SDK_Callback.o SDK_Callback.s
make: *** No rule to make target `C:/Program', needed by `xxx_SDK.o'.    Stop.
Generating scatter loading file.
make: del: Command not found
make: [makefile:140: clean] Error 127 (ignored)
```

my compiler is located at "C:\Program Files\ARM"
and I can even see that it is installed properly.

```
$ armcc --vsn
ARM/Thumb C/C++ Compiler, RVCT3.1 [Build 1055]
For support see http://www.arm.com/support/
Software supplied by: ARM Limited
```

based on ifeq   ($(TERM),cygwin) condition, it should detect the shell to be cygwin (which I am using) and use rm- rf for delete operation and also follow the unix path and line endings. But looking at the errors looks like the makefile is still running under a windows shell (del is used instead of rm -rf)

Is there some configuration under cygwin that has changed or needs to be enabled for it to work as a unix shell?

I have already downloaded the whole 'devel' section of cygwin, just to be sure including 'make' and 'g++' options.

I have also included the cygwin path in the environment variables.

One more clue I have is, it used to work fine on my older system, I started seeing the problem after I switched to a new system and installed everything (cygwin, compiler) again.

Is this a cygwin problem? or the makefile?

Any help is appreciated thanks !

Comment: what does `$(info TERM = $(TERM))` show you?

Comment: Update:     I changed ifeq    ($(TERM),cygwin)  to ifeq    ($(TERM),xterm) and it worked, looks like the terminal name was changed at some point of cygwin updates.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I changed ifeq ($(TERM),cygwin) to ifeq ($(TERM),xterm) and it worked, looks like the terminal name was changed at some point of cygwin updates.